# How to prevent users from copying shared documents in Google Docs / Google Drive

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api, copy-protection

I am using Google Drive to share documents only with certain users. Users can see them, add comments and even edit them in some cases. But what if I don't want them to make copies. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not, really. Use see some sort of **copy** from their machine already, so the best is to not show them your docs at all.

Comment: What a pity. Thank you anyway.